# jQuery Filter function when page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today i add this jQuery and working fine but i need when page is reload again submit button to be hidden. How to do that with jQuery function - to add function that check on every load and button to be hidden when is validate?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitGuestAccount").click(function () {
        if($("#email").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_firstname").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_lastname").val().trim().length>0 )   {
            $('#new_account_form p.submit').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want your button to be visible the first time the page is loaded until it is hidden by someone clicking somewhere and then to stay hidden after any number of reloads?

Comment: I want on every page load to add check for this code. If is valid button to be hidden. If is invalid button to be show. But button to be visible or invisible if($("#email").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_firstname").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_lastname").val().trim().length>0 )

Comment: Well, your function is fired after every page reload since you are firing it whenever the document is ready, therefore I do not actually understand where the problem is.

Comment: This jQuery i use in one checkout page (prestashop ecommerce) when i save account button disappear but if i reload page button show`s again. (when i click on field from account form (it is visible after account creation) button disappear and i don`t know why show`s up when realod (or go to other page and return back to checkout)

Comment: Your explanation in first comment is correct - that`s i want to make.

Comment: Because there is no such thing as a persistance in javascript, you can't track state of variables (such us whether the button is visible or hidden) after reload.

Comment: use a cookie or local storage to keep track across page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically 2 options:

1. Create session (e.g. in PHP) and store the state of the button in session data which will be then used during the page load.
2. Use ajax preloader to swap body contents of your current page and the preloaded one without actually reloading the page.

But you can't make this work with pure javascript because there is no such thing as persistance (you can't track state of variables trough reloads and/or going to another page and then returning back).

Comment: You can track page states with javascript if you use something like Angular.

You would run the control's scope properties through something that would bind them to the URL (using JSurl or something)

Example: http://resin-io.github.io/ngUrlBind/example1/#?user=~(firstName~'asdf~lastName~'asdf)

Comment: This is not a persistence, it just adds some params to your URL so when you reload page it can get the state out of it but if you leave the page or navigate away, all this is lost. And one more thing, it is painfull if you do more such url encoding and then you try back button.